# Как загрузить изображение из url ссылки в data message firebase cloud messaging когда приложение закрыто

Tags: firebase-android

Сообщения firebace cloud messaging делятся на 2 вида - notification и data. С помощью data сообщений удаётся получать уведомления в любом режиме работы приложения - закрыто/открыто/в фоне. Во время получения сообщения срабатывает метод onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) находящийся в FirebaseMessagingService. При попытке загрузки изображения из интернета - например с помощью Glide (испытывал разные методы) - происходит ошибка загрузки связанная с отсутствием интернета. Сервис находится внутри модуля. У модуля есть свой файл android manifest в котором указаны следующие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

подобные разрешения указаны и в манифесте приложения

сервис расширяющий FirebaseMessagingService в манифесте:

```
          <service
        android:name="com.test.test.PushMessagingService"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

То есть в результате получения уведомления при закрытом приложении - уведомление будет показано но без изображения.

Создается ощущение что во время работы FirebaseMessagingService приложение не предоставляет интернет

Я вышел из ситуации за счет того что в момент получения уведомления я активирую foreground service - в таком случаи картинка загружается. Однако это создает дополнительное уведомление - "приложение выполняется" и меня это не устраивает.
Кто ни будь еще сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Какое есть решение?